# Convergence conditions for two integrals

Tags: integration

For which respective $p$ values do the following two integrals converge?
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^p -x},$$

$$\int_1^\infty x^p \sin(1/x^2)  \,dx.$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x^p-x}\sim_\infty\frac{1}{x^p}\quad\text{if}\; p>1$$
and since
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^p-x}{x-1}=p-1$$
so
$$\frac{1}{x^p-x}\sim_1\frac{1}{(p-1)(x-1)}$$
and since the integral
$$\int_1^A\frac{dx}{x-1}$$
is divergent so the given integral is divergent for all $p$ *(the case $p<1$ is obvious).*

For the second integral we have
$$x^p\sin\left(\frac 1 {x^2}\right)\sim_\infty x^{p-2}$$
so the given integral is convergent if and only if $2-p>1\iff p<1$.

Comment: You use asymptotics for $x$ close to $1$,then you use that approximation in the limit when $x \rightarrow \infty$, which is not valid.

Comment: Can you explain why it isn't valid?

Comment: You show (correctly) that \textbf{when $x$ is close to $1$}, then $\frac{1}{x^p-x} \approx \frac{1}{(p-1)(x-1)}$.  But the you use that to approximete the integral $\int_1^A \frac{dx}{x^p-x}$ with the integral $\int_1^A \frac{dx}{(p-1)(x-1)}$, that is , you use the approximation also for large values of $x$, but that is invalid.

Comment: Why downvote?!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer for the first.

If you compare the function with $\frac{1}{x^p}$, then you get:

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x^p}}{\dfrac{1}{x^p - x}} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{x^p - x}{x^p} = \lim_{x\to \infty} 1-\dfrac{1}{x^p} = 1 $$

and that mean that the convergence of our function is the same as the convergence of $\dfrac{1}{x^p}$, and that depends on $p$:

If $p > 1$ : it converges,
else: it doesn't.